# Selenium invoking remotely using batch script

Tags: batch-file, selenium

I have my selenium project residing in machine X. I use a batch script sel_script to start the test remotely from a machine Y(Another batch script calls sel_script). Machine Y have IE version 11(Not possible to downgrade) and IEDriver does not support IE version 11. So errors popup on executing. Is there a way to keep sel_script file in machine Z and call this from machine Y. And test should be executed with machine Z's settings.(IE version of machine Z)

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like u want remote desktop rather than program code windows help setting up a remote desktop or getting help from a friend in this case X is Z's bestie

Comment: sorry ment Y in steda X they all look alike 2 me